# Trying to find a better way in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm kind of newbie in jQuery and wrote some jQuery code to show info about each football team when the user click on the team logo of each team.

I used `index()` to determine which `<div>` element was clicked.

And I think that must be a better way to write this code without using `index()` for this and without specify the `<p>` element with classes `a,b and c`.

Hope you can help, here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <style>
        .w3-card{
            width: 30%;
            margin-right: 10px;
            background-color: gainsboro;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        /*.w3-card:hover{*/
               /*background-color: #B0B0B0;*/
        /*}*/

        p{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        img{
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            display: block;
        }

        .container{
            width: 50%;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .imgc{
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right: -20px;
        }

        .info{
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #82ABE5;
            display: none;
            padding: 5px;
        }

    </style>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function () {

            var a = "Juventus is one of the strongest team in Italy";
            var b = "Barcelona is a spanish team";
            var c = "Real madrid has the most awards in europe";

            $('.w3-card').hover(function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#B0B0B0");
            },
            function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", "gainsboro");
            });

            $('.w3-card').click(function () {
                var index = $(this).index();

                $('.info').slideUp(400, function () {
                    $('p.a').hide();
                    $('p.b').hide();
                    $('p.c').hide();

                   if(index == 0){
                       $('.info').slideDown(400);
                       $('.a').show();
                   }
                   if(index == 1){
                       $('.info').slideDown(400);
                       $('.b').show();
                   }
                   if(index == 2){
                       $('.info').slideDown(400);
                       $('.c').show();
                   }

                });
            })

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="imgc">
                <div class="w3-panel w3-card"><img src="img/juve.png"><p>Juventus</p></div>
                <div class="w3-panel w3-card"><img src="img/barca.png"><p>Barcelona</p></div>
                <div class="w3-panel w3-card"><img src="img/real.png"><p>Real Madrid</p></div>
        </div>

        <div class="info">
            <p class="a">Juventus Football Club colloquially known as Juve  is a professional Italian association football club based in Turin, Piedmont.</p>
            <p class="b">Futbol Club Barcelona commonly known as Barcelona and familiarly as Barça is a professional football club based in Barcelona, Catalonia, Spain.</p>
            <p class="c">Real Madrid Club de Fútbol Royal Madrid Football Club), commonly known as Real Madrid, or simply as Real outside Spain frontiers, is a professional football club based in Madrid, Spain.</p>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're making this hard on yourself by how you're structuring the html.  Why not group the info with its respective image instead of having one container with images and one for info?

Comment: Another solution is add a data attribute on each div team (eg: `data-team="a"`) and then just catch it: `const team = $(this).attr('data-team');` to show the corresponding info: `$(`.${team}`).show();`.

Comment: Could you please edit your title so that it has something to do with your question? "Trying to find a better way in jquery" doesn't really help people find this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it would be to have a custom `data-*` attribute on your clickable elements. You're already using a common class, so this isn't much a change:

```
<div class="w3-panel w3-card" data-target="a">
```

And then use it:

```
$('.w3-card').click(function () {
    var target = $(this).data("target");
    $('.info').slideUp(400, function () {
        $('.info').slideDown(400);
        $('.' + target).show();
    });
});
```

Comment: I exactly said this to him in a comment. This is the most practic solution.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía - Hah, yeah I saw your comment right when I clicked post. Always happy to be on the same page as someone else.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best refactor would be to pull the info out into a javascript variable so you don't have so many dom elements. With more football/soccer teams on the page, it could get hard to manage.

With this refactor, you would create an object to hold info for all teams, and then insert into the `#info` div when one of the images is clicked. Here's the code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <style>
        .w3-card{
            width: 30%;
            margin-right: 10px;
            background-color: gainsboro;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        /*.w3-card:hover{*/
               /*background-color: #B0B0B0;*/
        /*}*/

        p{
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        img{
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            display: block;
        }

        .container{
            width: 50%;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .imgc{
            margin-left: 20px;
            margin-right: -20px;
        }

        #info{
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #82ABE5;
            display: none;
            padding: 5px;
        }

    </style>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>

        $(function () {

            var a = "Juventus is one of the strongest team in Italy";
            var b = "Barcelona is a spanish team";
            var c = "Real madrid has the most awards in europe";

            var info = {
                juve: 'Juventus Football Club colloquially known as Juve  is a professional Italian association football club based in Turin, Piedmont.',
                barca: 'Futbol Club Barcelona commonly known as Barcelona and familiarly as Barça is a professional football club based in Barcelona, Catalonia, Spain.',
                real: 'Real Madrid Club de Fútbol Royal Madrid Football Club), commonly known as Real Madrid, or simply as Real outside Spain frontiers, is a professional football club based in Madrid, Spain.'
            };

            $('.w3-card').hover(function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", "#B0B0B0");
            },
            function () {
                $(this).css("background-color", "gainsboro");
            });

            $('.w3-card').click(function () {
                var team = $(this).data('team');

                $('#info').slideUp(400, function () {

                    $('#info').html('<p>' + info[team] + '</p>').slideDown(400);

                });
            })

        });

    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="imgc">
                <div class="w3-panel w3-card" data-team='juve'><img src="img/juve.png"><p>Juventus</p></div>
                <div class="w3-panel w3-card" data-team='barca'><img src="img/barca.png"><p>Barcelona</p></div>
                <div class="w3-panel w3-card" data-team='real'><img src="img/real.png"><p>Real Madrid</p></div>
        </div>

        <div id="info"></div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```